# Why is the determinant non-zero

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, determinant

Since $T(y)$ is globally insufficient, there exist a $T_1$ and sets of positive measure $Y_{11}$ and $Y_{12}$ which are disjoint and subsets of $Y_1=(y \vert T(y)=T_1)$ such that:
$$
\frac{g_a(Y_{11},a)}{g(Y_{11},a)} \not= \frac{g_a(Y_{12},a)}{g(Y_{12},a)} \qquad (1)
$$

solve the system:
$$
ds_{11}g(Y_{11},a)+ds_{12}g(Y_{12},a)=-ds_{2}g(Y_{2},a) \qquad (2)
$$
$$
ds_{11}g_a(Y_{11},a)+ds_{12}g_a(Y_{12},a) =\frac{u^\prime_2 }{u^\prime_1}  ds_{2}g_a(Y_{2},a) \qquad (3)
$$

[The entire proof to which my question refers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Chm32.png)

[The Theorem of the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACohz.png)

The system (2) and (3)
has a solution because (1) implies that the determinant is nonzero. Can someone explain why (1) implies that the system has a solution?

Thanks in advance and if something is unclear about the question please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

according to (1) $ g_{a}(Y_{11},a)g(Y_{12},a)≠g_{a}(Y_{12},a)g(Y_{11},a) $
now try to get the determinant for your system. It can only be zero, if $ g_{a}(Y_{11},a)g(Y_{12},a) - g_{a}(Y_{12},a)g(Y_{11},a) = 0 $, but it's not according to the forementioned info.

Comment: Thanks! So i rerange (2) and (3): $$\frac{ds_{11}g_a(Y_{11},a)+ds_{12}g_a(Y_{12},a)}{ds_{11}g(Y_{11},a)+ds_{12}g(Y_{12},a)} =\frac{u^\prime_2 }{u^\prime_1}  $$ and then the determinant is $$g_a(Y_{11},a)g(Y_{12},a)-g_a(Y_{12},a)g(Y_{11},a)$$ which can not be zero. So the system have a solution?